# 英語が残っている: The question owner accepted this as the best answer XXX

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

### 他の人が選んだAccepted answerの緑色チェックマーク

マウスポインタでポイントすると

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer XXX.

(XXXは`昨日`や`11時間前`など。ここだけ日本語。リソースからとってきている？)

### ベストアンサーを選ぶ質問者側から見える灰色のチェックマーク

こちらも同様にポイントすると

> Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)

### 自分で選んだ場合の緑色チェックマーク

> Click to undo acceptance of this answer; you accepted this answer XXX

(XXXは`昨日`や`11時間前`など)

Comment: 「自分で選んだ場合の緑色チェックマーク」のケースを追加しました。XXXには「10月10日 13:01」のような日付+時刻が表示される場合もあります。スクリーンショット: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDtD7.png

Answer (score 1):

### 翻訳案 (緑色チェックマーク)

> 質問者はこの回答をXXXベストアンサーとして選びました。

(XXXは原文と同様)

### 例

> 質問者はこの回答を昨日ベストアンサーとして選びました。

### 翻訳案 (灰色チェックマーク)

> この回答が問題を解決した・または解決方法を見つける上で最も役に立った場合は、クリックしてベストアンサーとして承認してください。

**EDIT 注: `Accepted answer`に相当する単語をここでは`ベストアンサー`と表記していますが、本報告投稿現在はまだ確定していません。**

Comment: [専門用語のポスト](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E)では「ベストアンサー」より「はなまるアンサー」がいいかなと思っていました。適用する前に、そこで専門用語を討議した上でこれを合わせる必要もあると思います。

Comment: @jmac すみません、変化の可能性がある単語について考慮していませんでした。さっき「はなまるアンサー」についてコメントしたつもりだったのですが投稿を忘れていました。そちらもご確認ください。

Answer (score 1):

英語版の内容に加えて、「押すと解決済みになる」という情報を入れ込んだ案です:

### 未採用の灰色チェックマーク

> この回答をベストアンサーとして選んで質問を解決済みにします。この回答のおかげで問題が解決した、またはこの回答が最も解決の役に立った場合に選んでください。（もう一度クリックすることで取り消せます）

### 自分で採用した緑のチェックマーク

> ベストアンサーとしての採用を取り消して、この質問を未解決にします。採用日付：

### 他の人が採用した緑のチェックマーク

> 質問者がこの回答を最も役に立つ回答として採用しました。採用日付：